# SVN export leads to E020024: Error resolving case

Tags: linux, powershell, svn, path

I've been having a very weird error using svn export. Calling this command from within a powershell script:

```
svn export svnFilePath \\abcd.aa.bb\aaa_b_c6$\abcdef\Abcdef\abcdef
```

which leads to

```
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of \\abcd.aa.bb\aaa_b_c6$\abcdef\Abcdef\abcdef
```

Now i've tried reversing the slashes like this

```
svn export svnFilePath //abcd.aa.bb/aaa_b_c6$/abcdef/Abcdef/abcdef
```

or using single quotation and double quotation marks but the end result is the same. I believe it has something to do with the server `\\abcd.aa.bb\` because the same command works if it's used on another server `\\xyz.aa.bb\`. I don't have access to these Servers, as they're managed by someone else, to check for any differences unfortunately. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: What is svnFilePath and the actual path to the network share?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2016? Please, upvote and accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the error `svn: E020024: Error resolving case of` indicates that the network share is inaccessible by the user account under which you run `svn export`. I suggest double-checking access permissions configured on the network share and the UNC path you enter.